# How to center data table header and data using in bootstrap w/o using CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables-1.10

I am starting to learn asp.net mvc4 and bootstrap so far I managed to create this Data table. I am using the current default `CSS` of the mvc4 the `Site.css`. W/o modifying the css how can I center the Header `(Name)` and the data `(A B C D)` of my datatable?. If it is not possible how to edit it in `CSS`?. I only have a basic knowledge in `css`

[image: PICTURE]

Here is my code of my JS

```
var globalPersonId = 1;
var dataTablesOrderedList = "";
$(document).ready(function () {

var dataTablesFirstBS = $('#dataTables-FIrstSample').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    info: true,
    search: true,
    stateSave: true,
    order: [[1, "asc"]],
    lengthMenu: [[50, 100, 200, -1], [50, 100, 200, "All"]],
    ajax: { "url": "/BS/GetFirstDataTable" },
    columns:
    [
        { data: "BSId", title: "", visible: false, searchable: false, sortable: false },
        { data: "Name", title: "Name", sClass: "alignCenter", sortable: false },
        {
            data: "ActionMenu", title: "Sample Button", width: "100px", sAlign: "alignCenter", searchable: false, orderable: false, sClass: "alignCenter",
            "mRender": function (data) {
                return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs action" id="btnAddToCart_' + data + '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery glyphicon-fw action"></i></button>';
            }
        }
    ]
});

//    MyFirstBS();
function MyFirstBS() {

    dataTablesOrderedList = $('#tblMyFirstBS').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        processing: true,
        info: true,
        retrieve: true,
        destroy: true,
        search: true,
        stateSave: true,
        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
        ajax: {
            "url": "/BS/GetFirstDataTable",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.BSId = globalPersonId;
            }
        },
        columns:
    [
        { data: "BSId", title: "", visible: false, searchable: false, sortable: false },
        { data: "Name", title: "Name", searchable: false, sortable: false }
    ]
    });
   }
  });
```

Comment: ow sorry i didn't mention above. So far I try to add `align:"center"` but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using CSS is the best/preferred way of styling HTML.**

For horizontal text alignment, Bootstrap has some helper CSS classes:

```
<p class="text-left">Left aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text.</p>
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

For table cell alignment you could make your own helper CSS classes and use those:

```
.text-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.text-bottom {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Alternatively you could add custom CSS classes to your datatable:

```
<table class="example-class"> ... </table>
```

And then use that to style your cells:

```
.example-class th {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.example-class td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: @KiRa not sure what you mean by hard coded? If you mean in HTML, then you could use the `valign` attribute on the cell. But that is obsolete and deprecated since HTML5 was introduced. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: just like i said last time like `align: center`

Comment: @KiRa Have you read the information on the page I linked you to? That will tell you all about it.